# AmazonDynamoDBLockClient - Heartb eat thread recieved interrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

have this error in AmazonDynamoDBLockClient. Im using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:2.0.1.RELEASE`

```
#Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder properties
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.cdcInput.group=listener
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.cdcInput.destination=my_stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.cdcInput.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.auto-create-stream=false
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.locks.table=LockRegistry
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.checkpoint.table=MetadataStore
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.locks.leaseDuration=10
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.locks.heartbeat-period=3
```

and here is my application.properties configs

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient - Heartbeat thread recieved interrupt, exiting run() (possibly exiting thread)
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.run(AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.java:1184)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessa
geDrivenChannelAdapter - stopped KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=TRIM_HORIZON, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='binlog_updates', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}], consumerGroup='cdc-listener'}

[-kinesis-shard-locks-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageD
rivenChannelAdapter - Error during unlocking: DynamoDbLock [lockKey=cdc-listener:rds_binlog_updates:shardId-000000000000,lockedAt=2021-01-21@15:54:36.735, lockItem=null]
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to release lock at cdc-listener:binlog_updates:shardI
d-000000000000; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.integration.aws.lock.DynamoDbLockRegistry$DynamoDbLock$ reject
ed from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
org.springframework.integration.aws.lock.DynamoDbLockRegistry$DynamoDbLock.unlock(DynamoDbLockRegistry.java:526)
org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumerManager.run(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:1294)
```

We are getting this error even if the stream is empty and no data is read by consumer. Service starts application context as regular without any errors, but in 1-2 minutes such an error appears and application falls down.

Comment: Running into the same thing, did you ever figure out a solution?